# What is the rotatable switch used in smartwatches called?

Tags: components, potentiometer

Some smartwatches such as an apple watch and Samsung Gear use a rotatable switch for navigation that make a clicking sound when turned. The companies call it "crown" ([some details - pdf](https://www.tdcommons.org/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2338&context=dpubs_series#:%7E:text=Crowns%20are%20often%20employed%20for,employed%20in%20smartwatches%20for%20navigation.)). I'm trying to replicate the same for my arm computer more or less. I can't find it anywhere on the web.

The closest I got to was something called "selector switch" ([images](https://www.google.com/search?q=selector+switch&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIN1007US1029&hl=en-GB&prmd=sivn&sxsrf=APwXEdcD_fKqq9O0kJNUKFVVLjq0cPX-5w:1683715668845&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIneDSyer-AhUFSTABHQluAOEQ_AUoAnoECAIQAg&biw=1180&bih=701&dpr=2)) but they seem way expensive to be the same. And also they seem to have very less divisions. The actual switch is a modified potentiometer with many divisions as far as I am guessing.

[Video of crown of Apple](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=kZEgup5ijd4) 
[Similar thing, but it's a rotating bezel not crown, by Samsung](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=YGFz291RpUs)

Few images:

[image: The crown]

[image]

Comment: Sometimes they use rotary encoders as switches. It isn't a switch, it just gives a pulse indicating a "unit" of rotation and that will also give you direction. A search for rotary encoder swtiches gets quite a few options. You say "very less divisions" by which I guess you mean there aren't many positions, how many were you thinking? My experience of those devices is looking at 8 positions in a full rotation.

Comment: Post a picture of the thing you seek to replace/mimic rather than images of stuff you found while looking for a replacement. Most of the stuff in that list are panel mount 2 position selector switches but it actually sounds like you are looking for an potentiometer, encoder or rotary switch - all of which are different things.

Comment: You would also be interested in *rotary encoders* (the kind designed for attaching knobs) which have no end stops and many clicks (sometimes no clicks). For example these are used in car stereo volume knobs, and computer mouse scroll wheels.

Comment: Are you talking about the rotating bezel? Post a picture and put arrows on it to pinpoint what you mean. It won't use a potentiometer but, you need to tell us and show us more.

Comment: @Lundin Really sorry I didn't post a picture. I thought it might be quite popular. You can check now. Thanks!

Comment: @user253751 The rotatory encoders look quite promising but it is a smoothly rotating potentiometer right? Or are there variants of it with divisions like as in a crown (which aids proper navigation) Enlighten me please. Thanks!

Comment: @Andyaka Yes exactly. That's more or less the same thing

Comment: "rotary encoder" refers to things that can be designed for people to turn knobs, or to measure axles for example. The ones designed for people to turn often have many detents (divisions). The ones designed to measure axles don't have detents and they are probably also the wrong shape and size.

Comment: @Puffafish That was helpful. Thankyou! I am expecting like 20 25 divisions but 8 will also do. As I just need it for stepped navigation. Just to confirm before I buy one of these.. these are the same thing/ can function similar to a crown right?

Comment: @user253751 That doesn't sound like something I will be able to use for the purpose. Thanks for helping out though :)

Comment: a lot of big products like Apple products include custom Apple parts. You can make your own detents with a couple of 3D-printed pieces

Comment: The difference between rotary switches and rotary encoders is that the a rotary switch is just a "dumb" thing shorting two points at a time - the one you have selected against a common one, whereas an encoder is something "smart" and able to produce specific signals as output, either through mechanical means or built-in electronics. Either would have the mechanical 'click' as you turn them as an option. Also these are often panel mount/through-hole and quite large.

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, it's called a crown because that's what the knob for winding mechanical watches is called. https://evnwatches.com/blogs/news/watch-the-crown-the-history-of-the-wristwatch-crown

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for pointing that out! I almost bought a switch! Close call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically this is just a particularly small mechanical rotary encoder. Similar to a large encoder with a 6mm or 6.35mm shaft, it will have a pair of contacts that operate in quadrature (from which rotation and direction can be determined by an MCU) and a SPST switching function if the crown is pressed.

One can find such things that are roughly cube-shaped and 3-5mm on a side. Any more and I'd have to link to actual products, and finding those is really your job.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help! Apart from the description of it.. I managed to take apart two of my spare mouses apart and it seems like it's the same thing, a rotatory encoder (3 pins). Though struggling to see how to make use of it. I am guessing it works like any other encoder.

Comment: There's a difference between optical and mechanical encoders. The latter have some advantages (cost, maybe lower power) but you need to deal with the contacts bouncing.

Comment: Omg! I didn't know they use optical scroll wheels in mouses too! That's so cool. However, mine is a mechanical (magnetic?) one. I cant find anything on how to use that though.. maybe i'll ask a question after some more digging  :) https://superuser.com/questions/1271240/how-does-a-logitech-scroll-wheel-detect-movement